# Local scripts with Check MK on WIndows XP

Tags: batch-file, agent, check-mk

I have some issues using local scripts with Check MK on Windows XP.
Indeed, I don't know where I need to put my scripts to have information on Check Mk. The version I'm using is 1.6.0p30 and the agent version on XP is 1.5.0p25.
On Windows 7 or 10, we need to put scripts in C:\ProgrammData\agent\check_mk\local but on XP the folder "ProgramData" don't exsit.
My scripts use OpenHardewareMonitorReport.exe to get the CPU temp and FAN rpm.

I've tried to put my scripts in folder "C:\Program Files\check_mk\local but nothing.
I've tried to update the agent version but I can't.

Comment: The equivalent location for ```"%ProgramData%\agent\check_mk\local"``` on Windows XP would be ```"%AllUsersProfile%\Application Data\agent\check_mk\local"```.

Comment: Thanks but I find the location. It's C:\Program Files\check_mk\local.

Comment: I never told you the location! I gave you the Windows XP default equivalent location to the Windows Vista+, _(you said Windows 7 and Windows 10)_, location you told us is used for your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I found the location. It's `C:\Program Files\check_mk\local`.